# php files to be downloaded displayed in browser instead of downloaded

Tags: php

I am trying to get a text file to download using a PHP script but when my script runs the file contents are  displayed in the browser window. I tried this solution: [Why downloaded file is not downloaded instead it is shown in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177926/why-downloaded-file-is-not-downloaded-instead-it-is-shown-in-browser) 
However the code I have already has a content length header. This is my PHP code (which I obtained from another post [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315951/using-the-browser-prompt-to-download-a-file) and modified for a text file)

```
$file = 'file.txt';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

[Browser output of text file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q179P.png)

I tried to copy an example from php.com for a pdf file and I get the same symbols as in the post I linked.

I am not sure why this is happening. I am running MAMP 3.5 with PHP version 5.6.10 on Chrome.

This has really baffled me since so far I have been able to find solutions online for everything I have done. As far as I can tell, what I am doing is correct so any advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Nehal Patel

RESOLVED (9/4/15) with guidance from Marcus:
removed flush() an ob_clean().

```
$file = 'file.txt';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;
```

Comment: I used to change `'Content-Disposition: attachment`to `'Content-Disposition: inline` and it displayed in a new tab, but this doesn't work anymore. Not sur ehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your content-type to octet/stream

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, I have tried that and I still get the same result.

Comment: Remove `ob_clean();` and `flush();`. Just keep `readfile($file);`